# Is there a command line way to disable suspend in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, suspend

Is there a command line way to disable suspend in Ubuntu 12.04?

I can only SSH to my 12.04, is there a way to disable suspend mode via command line?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work (adapted from [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/93542/how-to-disable-shutdown-reboot-suspend-hibernate)).

Create a file `/etc/polkit-1/50-local.d/disable-suspend.pkla` containing:

```
[Disable suspend]
Identity=unix-user:*
Action=org.freedesktop.upower.suspend;
ResultAny=no
ResultInactive=no
ResultActive=no
```

Comment: This worked well for me today (2013-09-22) on Ubuntu 12.04, except the directory name was /etc/polkit-1/localauthority/50-local.d

Comment: I am having huge problem with suspend so I don't dare to test this. But does it mean that, with this script, even if I order `suspend` (via close lid, via button, via menu button), Ubuntu will not go into suspend?

Comment: @anh yes, that's the idea.

Answer (score 5):

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (which uses systemd, unlike 12.04), I successfully used the following to disable suspend:

```
sudo systemctl mask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```

And this to re-enable it:

```
sudo systemctl unmask sleep.target suspend.target hibernate.target hybrid-sleep.target
```